# Getting NaN for length inside object, node , express

Tags: express, post

```
app.post('/add', (req, res) => { 
  const newperson = {
    id: person.lenght +1,
    Text: req.body.text,
    Type: req.body.type
  }
  person.push(newperson)
  console.log(person.slice(-1))
  res.json(newperson)
})
```

id: person.lenght +1, ///here person is a array,
Giving NaN for id.

Expecting to push the object to person array, but getting NaN for length.

Comment: `lenght` - don't you mean `length`?

Comment: The name `person` is singular, but you're using it to represent an array - it should have a plural name, like  `people` or `persons`.

Comment: @Dai Okay , will make changes thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the typo in "length".

Comment: Yes  , corrected the mistake it worked  thanks